CSS to Vertical Center Text fails on Two Side by Side Containers Placed in Class by HTML
I have two containers that have header text that changes via JavaScript. The text describes files listed in containers below them. The containers are side by side horizontally on the page (left to right). I have encompassed the two Containers in a class to apply Vertical and Horizontal Centering to both of them with this html code:
HTML
`<div class="Container_Headers">
    <div = "Container_FileList_Header"></div>
    <div = "Container_FileDesc_Header"></div>
</div>

`
The following CSS in a separate .css file is applied to the class.
CSS
`#Container_Headers {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}`



//Apply Classes via JavaScript
document.getElementById("Container_FileList_Header").setAttribute('class',"textstyle2     textstyle5 Container_Headers");
document.getElementById("Container_FileDesc_Header").setAttribute('class',"textstyle2 textstyle5 Container_Headers");

The CSS for the other textstyles is generated by RocketCake (the program I use to develop the website):
CSS
`.textstyle2 { font-size:12pt; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000;  }
.textstyle5 { text-align:center; }`

This code works fine on a single container and centers the text both horizontally and vertically. It fails to vertically center the text on two side by side containers however. The text is aligned to the top but centered horizontally.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example


The following CSS in a separate .css file is applied to the class.

But you are styling to an ID.

#Container_Headers {display: inline-flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}

You should style for class, not ID.
.container_headers {
  display: inline-flex;
  place-items: center;
}


I agree I should have styled for the class and not the container, but for some reason this is still not working. Do I need to apply these properties to the subcontainers within the class as well? Thanks for your help!

I got it to work, by removing "display: inline-block;" from the ID of the inner Divs in the class, but now the text-align:center; property no longer horizontally centers the text. How can I horizontally center text using display: inline-flex;?

justify-content: center; for anyone else who encounters the problem. Thanks Scheibo!
